# backbone.js collection fetch 0 results causing error

Tags: backbone.js

I have a backbone collection which is setup to fetch results (events in my case) from a URL and then perform a little bit of data manipulation on the response in a parse method. When there are results provided by the api (as follows), the fetch is successful and everything behaves as expected.

```
{
  events: [
   { event1... },
   { event2... },
   ...
  ]
}
```

However, when the resultset is empty (as follows), the fetch runs its error function instead of the success call, and never seems to execute my parse method at all.

```
{
  events: []
}
```

Is this behaving as expected? As in, should backbone be throwing the error when there are 0 results, and if so, is there any way of fixing this?

Comment: Sounds odd. Is the returned JSON valid? Is the http return code `200`? What is the errorText and error of the `error` callback arguments?

Comment: Thanks that seems to have resolved it. It turns out the API was returning 500 when there was no results. I didn't think to check (I didn't build it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was being triggered by the APIs HTTP response code (500). As a result, Backbone was behaving correctly.